# specifying binding source to usercontrol in listbox

Tags: wpf

How can I specify datasource for a user control:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">                                
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:ucMyControl />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</ScrollViewer>
```

How ucMyControl know what values to take?  I realize that lisbox will create as many ucMyControls as there are items in bondong collection?
Also, scrollviewers don't work - I can't get to 3rd control (they are all empty anyway, but I hope you'll give me leads how to bind it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control that is instantiated from an [ItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) in an `ItemsControls` (e.g. `ListBox`) has its [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) property automatically set to the appropriate item from the `Items` or `ItemsSource` collection of the ItemsControl.

So if you for example have a collection of `Person` objects with properties `FirstName` and `LastName` as ListBox items you can bind like this in your UserControl:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LastName}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

You do not need to set the DataContext property explicitly.

Comment: Why would I specify TextBlocks - I already have user control with controls and layout I need?

Comment: Yes, but how can i know that. This is only an example of how to bind.

Comment: And how can i databind to a usercontrol then?

Comment: Don't know what you mean. The UserControl has a DataContext property, which is automatically set and is the root of any binding paths within the control.

Comment: Well, strangely enough that user control doesnot display any values in it

Comment: Maybe you should post the XAML of your control and the code of the data (item) object you're going to bind to.

Comment: What about this one, are you still trying?

Comment: I noticed that designer wrote some sort of CollectionViewSource which I didn't ask for and don't understand what is that anyway.  Removing fixed the problem)